# Is there a way I can simplify my case when statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a code (spark-sql) that will classify partitioned data as ST.

[image]

Basically the goal is to end up with another column `Open ST` that will  only show open STs (open STs are determined by NOT having Task RW anywhere after ST).

End goal:

[image]

So in this case item`12346` will end up with ST because there is no Task RW anywhere after Task ST. Item `12345` won't be an open ST because RW is present somewhere after ST.

As you can see, other tasks can be present after ST but that's not necessarily relevant as I care about the Tasks ST and RW.

Any thoughts on how I can code this. To be fully transparent I have created other columns based on partitions like `NextTask`, Lag and `Lastvalue` and I'm using a  `CASE WHEN` clause with them but I think they might be complicating things for me:

```
CASE WHEN code_task = 'ST' AND lastvalue = 'CR' AND Lag_ NOT LIKE '%RW'AND Next_Task NOT LIKE '%RW%' THEN 'ST' END AS Open ST
```

Hoping there's a simpler solution by just looking the tables I'm providing. Thank you!

Comment: Can u accept the answer pls? I am sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is unclear in terms of data, here is an approach based on some assumptions made. No, not with case, but in another way.

**Code**

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// Unclear if code is asc or unique, otherwise a zipWithIndex needed. 
// Assumed code c can be used, seems that we just need to look for RW and it is after the ST.

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq( (1,7,"ST"), (1,8,"XX"), (1,9,"RW"), (3,10,"ST"), (3,11,"AA"), (3,12,"RW"), (2,3,"ST"), (2,4,"TT"))).toDF("i", "c", "t")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

val res = spark.sql(""" SELECT i as iN
                          FROM data
                         WHERE t = 'RW' 
                    """)
val temp = df.join(res, df("i") === res("iN"), "outer")
val results = temp.withColumn("openST", when(col("iN").isNull && col("t") === lit("ST"), lit("ST")).otherwise("")).select($"i", $"c", $"t", $"openST")
results.show(false)
```

**Results**

```
+---+---+---+------+
|i  |c  |t  |openST|
+---+---+---+------+
|1  |7  |ST |      |
|1  |8  |XX |      |
|1  |9  |RW |      |
|2  |3  |ST |ST    |
|2  |4  |TT |      |
|3  |10 |ST |      |
|3  |11 |AA |      |
|3  |12 |RW |      |
+---+---+---+------+
```